# How can I add a Windows partition to a Linux device?

Tags: windows, dual-boot, manjaro, gparted

There are any number of articles online describing how to turn your Windows box into a dual-boot Windows/Linux, but I can't find anything about how to go the other direction.

My laptop is running [Manjaro Linux](https://manjaro.org/), and I'd like to make it dual-boot Manjaro and Windows. I've downloaded a Windows 10 ISO from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10ISO), and used Balena Etcher to flash it to a USB. However, Etcher warns that the iso doesn't contain a partition table and is therefore not bootable. And sure enough: When I try to boot from the USB, nothing happens for a second and then I'm back on the screen where you choose which device to boot.

I'm sure I'm doing something wrong, but all those one-way articles I mentioned are making it hard to find any resources for what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Welcome, from GParted you can create a partition table.

Comment: Most tools assume hybrid ISO which can be written with dd. But Windows is not a hybrid, so any tool that actually uses dd  will not work And Windows now made .wim over 4GB, so it cannot be on a FAT32 partition unless split. For Windows ISO with .wim > 4GB
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2444665 & 
https://github.com/ValdikSS/windows2usb
Supposedly latest Windows made .wim file smaller so extraction works, but check.
https://techbit.ca/2019/02/creating-a-bootable-windows-10-uefi-usb-drive-using-linux/
Best just to use Windows to create Windows installer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create a bootable USB using [WoeUSB](https://github.com/WoeUSB/WoeUSB)

Install it using pacman:

```
sudo pacman -Syu woeusb
```

After that, change the directory to the downloaded iso and run where /dev/<usb_device> name of your USB flash drive. **Note: drive must be unmounted**.

```
sudo woeusb -v --device windows-10.iso /dev/<usb_device>
```

If you down know USB device name use **lsblk** command:

```
$ lsblk 
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0   64G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   60G  0 part /
├─sda2   8:2    0    1K  0 part 
└─sda5   8:5    0    4G  0 part [SWAP]
sdb      8:16   1 60.5G  0 disk 
└─sdb1   8:17   1 60.5G  0 part /media/user/64G
sr0     11:0    1 1024M  0 rom
```

so my device is **sdb**, and it mounted to the /media/user/64G, so I need to unmount it before running woeusb.

```
sudo umount /dev/sdb1
```

Answer (score 0):

You are asking, or have, two separate questions/problems happening...

> My laptop is running Manjaro Linux.  I'd like to make it dual-boot Manjaro and Windows.

So if you already have a system, having one disk, that disk will be partitioned in some manner.  Assuming the laptop is modern and has UEFI it [the motherboard] will want to see an EFI partition and a boot loader for it to execute to start a boot process and boot some operating system.  If it is an older laptop, with BIOS only and no UEFI, then I'll leave it to you to read up on MBR, but the concept is somewhat the same except no EFI partition.  But with UEFI, and requiring one EFI partition on the disk, last I knew Microsoft Windows and Linux [grub/grub2] did not play that well.  If memory serves it was *best* to start with the disk having windows installed, and then installing linux afterwards and it was grub2 that was able to make it work.

What would happen is when the motherboard goes to run the boot loader on the efi partition, grub2 of linux is more than happy to say hi I see you have windows also let me put that in the boot menu for you as an N*th* option.  Windows on the other hand, is exclusive and only wants to know about itself and does not support any kind of dual boot, so if you install windows after having linux installed then windows is going to blow away the existing efi partition for itself and not preserve your linux install.  At least this has been my understanding which is why i favor a separate disk for linux and a separate disk for windows, and let the motherboard boot settings choose which disk to boot.  Now you likely can't have 2 disks on your laptop so with one disk you have to plan way ahead.

*Can you have 2 efi partitions on one disk, and tell the UEFI on the motherboard which one to boot ?*  I am not sure, If anyone knows this answer let me know as a comment.

> However, Etcher warns that the iso doesn't contain a partition table and is therefore not bootable. And sure enough: When I try to boot from the USB, nothing happens for a second and then I'm back on the screen where you choose which device to boot.

this question is about putting an iso to a usb and having it bootable for an operating system install.  For a linux `.iso` it as simple as

```
# usb stick shows up as /dev/sde  for example
# and may have any number of partitions such as sde1 and sde2 and so on.

# simply do this, you do not have to mount anything.

cp    CentOS-7-x86_64-DVD-2003.iso   /dev/sde
```

Then that usb will be bootable.  If the iso can readily be burned to a dvd and be bootable, then this simple copy method to the block device makes that device (the usb stick) bootable so it should work with whatever microsoft windows iso.